# After closing a popup window and check another checkbox previous checkbox gets checked as well

Tags: jquery, checkbox, kendo-grid

I have a weird thing going on when opening a popup window..Here are the steps and the relative code

1) Check a checkbox from the row

2) Click on Edit button

The code for the edit button is

```
$(".myEdit").click(function () {
    GetSelectedIDs(this.id);
})
function GetSelectedIDs(btn) {
    var idsToSend = [];
    var grid = $("#Customer-Grid").data("kendoGrid")
    var ds = grid.dataSource.view();

    for (var i = 0; i < ds.length; i++) {
        var row = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + ds[i].uid + "']");
        var checkbox = $(row).find(".checkbox");
        if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
            idsToSend.push(ds[i].CustomerID);
        }
    }
    switch (btn) {
        case "delete": {
            if (idsToSend.length > 0) {
                Confirmation("delete", idsToSend);
            }

        }
            break;
        case "edit": {
            if (idsToSend.length > 1) alert("You can only edit one record at a time");

            else if (idsToSend.length == 0) alert("Need to select at least one record");

            else {
                HomeStorage.Keys.StringOfIDs = idsToSend;
                HomeStorage.Keys.CustomersID = idsToSend;
                CustomerUpdateEditor();
            }
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the CustomerUpdateEditor

```
function CustomerUpdateEditor() {
    $("#showCustomerEdit").append("<div id='window'></div>");
    var myWindow = $("#window").kendoWindow({
        position: {
            top: 100,
            left: "30%"
        },
        width: "40%",
        //height: "36%",
        title: "Customer",
        content: "/Customer/CustomerEditor",
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        close: function (e) {
            $("#window").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");
    myWindow.open();//myWindow.center().open();
    HomeStorage.Keys.AddOrEdit = "Edit";
    GetStates();
}
```

and the button that closes this popup is

```
$("#btnClose").click(function () {
    ClearFields();
    CloseTheWindow();
    GetCustomerGridData();
});
```

The CloseTheWindow function is

```
function CloseTheWindow() {    
    $("#window").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

3) Now that the popup is closed and the CustomerGrid is refreshed, I check a different checkbox, well now what happens is that once I check the next checkbox the previous checkbox is checked as well and it doesn't make sense that it would happen, it shouldn't happen.

This is the Customer-Grid

```
function LoadCustomerGrid(newData) {
    $("#Customer-Grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: newData
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                CustomerID: { type: "number" }
            }
        },
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        columns: [
            {
                title: "<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox', class='check-box' />",
                template: "<input name='Selected' class='checkbox' type='checkbox'>",
                width: "30px"
            },
            {
                field: "CustomerID",
                title: "CustomerID",
                hidden: true
            },
        {
            field: "LastName",
            title: "Last Name",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: "FirstName",
            title: "Name",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: "Phone",
            title: "Phone",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: "Address",
            title: "Address",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: "City",
            title: "City",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: "Zip",
            title: "Zip",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains"
                }
            }
        }
        ],
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSize: 20
        },
        selectable: "row",
        height: $("#Customer-Grid").closest(".col-height-full").height() - 60,
        change: function (e) {
            // Function call goes here
            var detailRow = this.dataItem(this.select());
            var optionID = detailRow.get("CustomerID")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you made a snippet or jsFiddle showing the issue

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I am going to get one started right now

Comment: @DelightedD0D, So I went and created a snippet over on Kendo's dojo and tested it out and everything works fine over there. So that leaves me more confused on what is going wrong in my app